# Why is QTP's Recovery Scenario not triggering when I have a pop-up dialog that I need to dismiss?

Tags: dialog, qtp

I have a QTP script that interacts with a webpage. Occasionally, this webpage will pop-up dialogs that interfere with the rest of the test, and need to dismissed with a simple "OK" before I can continue running the test.

Recovery Scenarios are supposed to take care of this exact situation, but try as I might, QTP will never recognize the pop-up. The recovery scenario is set to trigger upon seeing a dialog with "Window title: Message from webpage". I used the object spy so I know that this is the correct identification.

Attached is the dialog box that the webpage occasionally displays. Very simple dialog, so why won't QTP recognize it?

[image: Message from webpage dialog box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, my Recovery Scenario was built correctly, but the problem I had was that QTP didn't know when to activate the Recovery Scenarios.

Go to `File > Settings > Recovery`, highlight the recovery scenario you want to have activate, then change `Activate recovery scenarios` to `On every step`.

By default, the recovery scenarios are only activated when **QTP** throws an error, *not* when your *web page* throws an error.
Lastly, having the recovery scenario check every step will probably degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect when this window appears like a page refresh, opening a new window or clicking on a button, or operating on a page for 2 long.
Then since this is a standard window you get, why don't you add in Object repository.
Then create a function which checks for this window's existence 
call this function when any of the suspected scenarios happen.
this will not degrade the performance badly comapred to recovery scenario.

Comment: That would work if there was a pattern to when the dialog appears, but the web page is completely a black box and the dialog appears at completely random times. But you are right that if there was a way to predict when the dialog might occur, to check for and handle the dialog then.